# Selenium: Download file to specific folder using chrome driver

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with chromedriver to automate a login page and download a file to particular folder. I am able to login and click on download link.But this downloads the file to default download folder. But i want the file to be downloaded to my desired folder.
I used below code(vb.net). I got it from [this link](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2012/06/11/downloading-files-with-webdriver) which is in C#

```
Protected Function downloadFile(ByVal driver As IWebDriver, ByVal url As String, ByVal localPath As String)
    Try
        Dim client = New WebClient()
        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie) = cookieString(driver)
        client.DownloadFile(url, localPath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function

Private Function cookieString(ByVal driver As IWebDriver) As String
    Try

        Dim cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies
        Dim a As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        For index As Integer = 0 To cookies.Count - 1
            a.Append(cookies(index).Name)
            a.Append("=")
            a.Append(cookies(index).Value)
            a.Append("; ")

        Next
        cookieString = a.ToString

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

But it does not work.The file downloaded contains html source of page , but actual file from that url should be a pdf(when I manually navigate the url in the same chrome window I get pdf file downloaded) what I am doing wrong?I think handling the cookies may be wrong in cookieString function. Or is there any other method to download files to my required path after i login to page.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå i have updated the question with the problems i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use `File.Move` to move your file from the default download folder to your desired folder

I am currently facing the same issue, and currently ChromeDrive cannot change the default download location

Comment: it can be put in a comment

Comment: I do not have enough points to comment OP's question, only able to answer, not even vote.